# Easy way to get text to "display:inline" when it is nested in about 5 generated DIV tags?

Tags: css, html, nested, inline

I can add a CSS class to the outer-most DIV and the inner-most DIV tags with "display:inline" but, I cannot do that with some in between.

The markup is something like this...

```
<span>ABC</abc>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
       XYZ
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the text ABC to be on the same line as the text XYZ, but because of the DIV tags, they are on seperate lines.

Comment: At the moment, your question makes little sense. You should provide a more complete HTML/CSS test case using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if there is a reason for you to have so many nested divs (you are unable to change the HTML etc.) you could apply a class to the outmost div and then use inheritence to apply `display: inline;`

**HTML**

```
<span>ABC</abc>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
       XYZ
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper, 
.wrapper div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the outermost div e.g. `myDiv`

CSS:

```
.myDiv, .myDiv div {
    display: inline;
}
```

That makes the myDiv div and all `div` elements that are descended from myDiv display inline.

HTML:

```
<span>ABC</span>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div>
    <div>
       XYZ
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/nTPZY/